# "He would go to the theater if I would go with him" - is this a correct sentence?

Tags: american-english, sentence, complex-sentences, will-would

How to say properly in American English this sentence:
"He would go to the theater if I would go with him".

Does it look absolutely fine? First of all, I'm curious about two "would" in one sentence.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a native speaker, but the way I learnt it, it should be ".. if I **went** with him".

Comment: A good answer would contain an explanation why to use "went".

Answer (score 3):

It's okay, but perhaps not what you mean. You perhaps mean:

> He would go to the theater if I went with him.

The *would* clause is conditional, but the clause used to give the condition is not itself in the conditional mood.

We might use your form if we had another reason for using *would*, like a double conditional:

> If it wasn't raining, I would go to the theater, and he would go to the theatre if I would go with him.

Or some past-tense uses:

> In those days I would often go to the theater, and he would go to the theater if I would go with him.

Even there though, *went* would be more common.